# Implementing Ajax calls for a REST API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, rest

I have built a back end REST API using Slim Framework and followed the REST format as close as I could.

Once I started working on the Front End I realized that AJAX works great with parameters and not paths

(param file?param=value , paths file/object/method/id)

I am planning on out sourcing or building an APP with xamarin or other 3rd party to consume the API, but for now a Alpha test will be done with HTML and AJAX calls.

Example call   example.com/user/test   or example.com/advertiser/2

So how do I query the API, do I just concat URL strings?

.ajax({ ...  url : 'example.com/user/'+user ...});

**EDIT:**

Yes I know AJAX is domain sensitive, and Yes I am using verbs GET,POST,PUT and DELETE.

What is going on is the following :

When passing variables in an AJAX request they get appended as

PARAMS example.com/users/?user=Pogrindis

in an REST API at least as far as I read it goes

example.com/users/Pogrindis that's a path

reference parse.com/docs/rest#general-quick

Comment: What ajax calls have you tried ? If is it cross domain permitted headers etc ?

Comment: No, my ajax requests work fine, I am curious how to model AJAX around a rest API format which is based on paths rather then params.

Comment: REST API call involves different VERBS to be used for the API to do action on those viz : GET,POST,PUT, DELETE. So you can use simple jquery ajax to send the request. For GET and DELETE you can send the params as query string and for POST and PUT use POST. Also beware when you use AJAX call for API end point the api end point must support cross domain request.

Comment: Yes, since jquery doesn't have any built-in queryparam->path conversion, you'll have to build the url yourself.

Comment: So why do people use REST if It seems not compatible with ajax? 
I only used the standard REST because it seems to be popular and I am still learning.

Comment: There are some javascript framework like ember.js which does it for you.

Comment: Here is the REST adapter for ember.js http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: I didnt know about that emberJS adapter, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research here is a solution used

**FRONT END**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/user/'+getid,
  data: getdatastring,
  type: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
  }
});
```

**BACK END**
SLIM PHP FRAMEWORK

```
$app->put('/user/:id', function($id) use ($app,$_pdo) {

    $obj = new dbModel($_pdo);

    $objApi = new Controller($obj);

    $arrParams = json_decode($app->request()->getBody(),true);

    $arrUser= $objApi->getUserInfo($id,$arrParams);



    print json_encode($arrUser);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax has set definitions how to do this : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your passing user as a param, over get // post method and you are specifying what you expect back.

If i understood the question correctly you are looking at something like:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'example.com/user/',
         data: {user: user}, // Params being sent
         type: 'post',// Or get
         dataType: 'json' // Or whatever you have 
         success: function(output) {
                      //.. do what you like
                  }
});
```

There should be no problem.

The data being passed into it will append to the url for GET-requests, i think thats what you mean.. Your data object can be constructed before sending via ajax.

There needs to be a route to query for data. Unless you define some flag on the server to point to the correct location, then you could pass through a route param but you need to have a pointer URL. Building the route can be painful, and subsequent calls will be more challenging but you can do it ?

Comment: I thought in rest API just like MVC its example.com/user/1
In slim you take params as PATHS like example.com/user/id/otherparam/3rdparam  
I thought the whole point of Rest is to use paths.

Comment: Yes, but they get appended as PARAMS example.com/users/?user=Pogrindis in an REST API at least as far as I read it goes 
example.com/users/Pogrindis  that's a path
reference https://parse.com/docs/rest#general-quick

Comment: But thats how an API works.. You have a url to query for data, unless you define some flag on the server to point to the correct location, then you could pass through a route param but you need to have a pointer URL.